# How to authenticate with Mailjet without getting errors related to node_modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, mailjet

I'm following Mailjet's docs [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?javascript#sending-a-basic-email-v3), but getting the following error when starting my app: `./node_modules/pac-resolver/dnsResolve.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/username/Desktop/projects/test-project/node_modules/pac-resolver'`

All I'm trying to do is connect to Mailjet with my API keys, like so:

```
import mailjet from 'node-mailjet';

  ...

  sendEmail() {
    mailjet.connect(process.env.MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC, process.env.MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE)
  }
```

Why does my entire app break because of this one piece of prerequisite code? How can I even begin to debug this?